# VS code lines and multilines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with vscode. Wen I type something in few line lines and press CTRL+S everything changes to one line.

- Example:

  1. Some text
  2. Some text
  3. Some text

and after that I press CTRL+S happened this:
 1. Some text 2. Some text 3. Some text

How can I fix that to stay in few lines after I press CTRL+S?

Sorry on my english still learning :)

Comment: hey there , what os are you using? mac or windows?

Comment: Hello :) 
windows

Comment: what file extension does the file you are editing have?

Comment: can you open command pallete , by ctrl+shift+p and then search join lines and check if ctrl+s has that

Comment: its html extension....
I cant find that on settings, join lines I will check again

Comment: Its just nothing happened, when I open command pallete and put join lines just not open anything.....and I try to check on settings but nothing again :(